# Multiple interfaces on Linux connected to multiple vlans

Tags: networking

I am thinking of creating the following network with a specific goal. Here is what I want to create

Linux 1 has 2 interfaces eth0 (10.1.1.1/24) eth1(192.168.10.x/24) 
Linux 2 has 2 interfaces eth0 (10.1.1.1/24) eth1(192.168.10.x/24) 
I also have a switch and would like to connect all these interfaces to the switch.
I build 2 vlans in the switch
vlan 1 - Vlan to connect management interfaces (port 2,4)
vlan 2 - Vlan for traffic (ports 3,5)

Current configuration is follows: 
Linux server#1 - eth0 - connected to port 2 
Linux server#2 - eth0 - connected to port 4 
Linux server#1 - eth1 - connected to port 3 
Linux server#2 - eth1 - connected to port 5

The switch is connected to an external gateway which provides the dhcp address 10.1.1.1/24
I want to send traffic between eth1 interfaces on both linux which have 192.168.10.x IP without disturbing the management traffic and hence I am having this configuration.

Question is: How can I get the 192.168.10.x Ip address ? Should I setup DHCP on one of the Linux boxes ? Is there any flaw in my network ?

Answer (score 0):

How ever you like.

- You could statically assign them.
- You could setup DHCP one of the Linux boxes.
- You could setup another server to act as a DHCP server on that VLAN.
- You could setup DHCP relaying on your switch and setup the DHCP that is responsible for the 10.1.1.0/24 scope as a DHCP server.